# React site on versel broke after commit

Tags: reactjs, typescript, git, github, vercel

I created a React application and decided to upload it to Vercel, everything was fine, then I noticed a bug and fixed it, pushed a commit, and after that the site broke. What can be done about it?

The structure of the running application looks like this:

[image]

Broken like this:

[image]

Broken app has 1 error:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

I decided to change the root folder during the build to /src and got the following errors:

sh: react-scripts: command not found

Error: Command "react-scripts build" exited with 127

BUILD_UTILS_SPAWN_127: Command "react-scripts build" exited with 127